# update multi rows with the same id

Tags: mysql, node.js

I need to update 3 rows in a table where they're connected with each other by same id(dailyId)..but I got the updated result like this

> [ { firstItem:  'Breakfast', secondItem: 'Some' },   { firstItem:
>   'Breakfast', secondItem: 'Some' },   { firstItem: 'Breakfast',
>   secondItem: 'Some' } ]

```
const meals =[ { firstItem: 'Lunch', secondItem: 'More' },
  { firstItem: 'Breakfast', secondItem: 'Some' },
  { firstItem: 'Snack', secondItem: 'None' } ]

meals.forEach((mealItem) => {
        console.log(mealItem);
        getConnection().query("UPDATE `dailydetailmeal` SET `mealName`='"+mealItem.firstItem+"',`quantity`='"+mealItem.secondItem+"'   WHERE `dailyDetailId`='"+dailyId+"'", (err,result) => {
          if (err) {console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(result);
          })
        })

mysql.createConnection({multipleStatments: true})
```

Comment: Why are these three separate queries, instead of a single query using `WHERE ... IN (...)`?

Comment: I need to update 3 rows with 3 differnt values but what I get is the 3 rows is updated with the same value..Don't know why?